# Highchart datetime x-axis : display end of month date instead of first day of month

Tags: highcharts

In my chart, I try to display end of month performances over one year (at 31 Jan, 29 Fev, ..., 31 Dec). X-axis is defined as follow:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%b %Y'
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the scale automatically adjust to the appropriate unit (Months) and display the first day of the Month. As a result, my first element (at 31 Jan) is displayed above "Feb 2012" (same issue for other elements).
I was wondering if I could rather display the end of month day on my x-axis. Any idea?

Thanks,

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Bec/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a custom [`xAxis.tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner) with the positions at which the tick should appear as follows

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var ticks = [
            Date.UTC(2012, 0, 31),
            Date.UTC(2012, 2, 31),
            Date.UTC(2012, 4, 31),
            Date.UTC(2012, 6, 31),
            Date.UTC(2012, 8, 30),
            Date.UTC(2012, 10, 30)];
        //dates.info defines what to show in labels
        //apparently dateTimeLabelFormats is always ignored when specifying tickPosistioner
        ticks.info = {
            unitName: "month", //unitName: "day",
            higherRanks: {} // Omitting this would break things
        };           
        return ticks;
    }
}
```

[Customize tick positions | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/9B6LY/)

Comment: especially the thing with "unitName" is needed, otherwise it will not work, it would display dates like numbers.. I was looking for this for hours. Thank you!

Comment: @Asped glad to be helpful